# Using Polymorphism with incompatible signatures

Tags: vb.net, design-patterns

Say I have a class structure like this:

```
Public class Person1
  inherits Person

public function Greeting(ByVal strGreeting As String)
  return strGreeting
end function

end class

Public class Person2
   inherits Person

public function Greeting()
  return "Hello"
end function

end class
```

I want to be able to use Polymorphism to call: Greeting i.e.

```
dim P1 As Person = New Person1
dim P2 As Person = New Person2

msgbox(P1.Greeting)
msgbox(P2.Greeting)
```

However, Person2 accepts an argument, so the signatures are not the same.  What is the solution to this?

Comment: you explicitly create P1 as an instance of `Person1` which does not have that signature.  It wont go looking for a method on a *different* type (P2) just because they inherit from the same base class.  Try starting with a `Greeting` method on the base class.

Answer (score 0):

Your person objects are instances of Types which *just happen* to inherit from some the same type.  As an instance of `Person1`, the `P1` object is not going to have any knowledge of methods contained in `Person2` because it is a different Type.

I am not quite sure what you are after, but here is one way to construct it:

```
Public MustInherit Class Person
    Public Property Name As String

    Public Sub New(n As String)
        Name = n
    End Sub

    ' "I dont care HOW they do it, but child types 
    '    must provide a Greeting() function"
    MustOverride Function Greeting() As String

    ' overload: takes an arg/different sig
    Public Overridable Function Greeting(strGreeting As String) As String
        Return String.Format("Greetings, {0} {1}", strGreeting, Name)
    End Function

End Class

Public Class Person1
    Inherits Person

    Public Sub New(n As String)
        MyBase.New(n)
    End Sub

    ' override with a specific form of address
    Public Overrides Function Greeting() As String
        Return "Hello, Mr " & Name
    End Function

End Class

Public Class Person2
    Inherits Person

    Public Sub New(n As String)
        MyBase.New(n)
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function Greeting() As String
        Return "Hello, Senorita " & Name
    End Function

End Class
```

Then:

```
Dim Pa1 As New Person1("Ziggy")
Dim Pa2 As New Person2("Zoey")

Console.WriteLine(Pa1.Greeting)
Console.WriteLine(Pa2.Greeting("Ms"))   ' uses base class overload
Console.WriteLine(Pa2.Greeting())
```

Output:

```
Hello, Mr Ziggy                ' from P1
Greetings, Ms Zoey             ' from base class
Hello, Senorita Zoey           ' from P2
```

The base class more commonly might define a default `Greeting` for all the inherited types, then some base classes might override it and others not depending on the class needed.

Comment: Thanks.  Is it not bad practice to put the method ByVal strGreeting As String in the superclass - because not all childs implement it?

Comment: the inherited classes don't *have* to implement it *because* it is defined in the base class.  If you wanted it only for Person1, then put it there but then that override is only available to that Type.

Comment: @w0051977 to clarify, both Persons have 2 greetings available: the one in their class and the one on the base class.  the test/demo shows the second output coming from the base class.  More usually, the simplest default will be on the base class, then more specialized on the derived classes.  Also, I am curious why this is still an open question.